# obtener ultimo actualizado fila id

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

### Contexto

Tengo una tienda en línea y tengo un sistema de cupones, los cupones tienen start_date, expire_date e id_coupon... y otros datos, en DB tienen 1 fila importante (id_coupon) en la tabla tbl_coupons y en la tabla tbl_products tienen otra fila importante, normalmente Actualmente, los cupones están vinculados para un producto usando id_coupon en la tabla de cupones y usando id_coupon en la tabla de productos con la identificación correspondiente para los artículos correspondientes.

---

### El *problema*

Solo muestro los cupones activos en una tabla, cuando la fecha de inicio del cupón es más grande que la fecha actual, el cupón comienza a tener un estado de validez 'caducada' en la fila de validez en tbl_coupons en la base de datos. Para tomar este cambio, tomo otra consulta de selección pero la condición (pregunta) sobre la fecha de caducidad del cupón es mayor que el día actual, si es así, tengo foreach para capturar datos y luego.

---

### El verdadero problema

Realicé una consulta de actualización del cupón que establece la validez en 0 y luego, e instantáneamente necesito desvincular el id_coupon del producto relacionado que actualizó para caducar en la primera consulta de actualización, pero no sé cómo obtener la última identificación del producto actualizado en primer lugar. Consulta de actualización para tomar la otra consulta relacionada con este producto exactamente se modificó antes.

> i have an idea of obtain the id_product linked to an coupon (one per
> one) and capturing these with the corresponding coupon with id_coupon
> data..but im confused with this..

---

Este es el código, estoy usando mysql y PDO:

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Bogota');
    $fecha_actual = date("d-m-Y");
    
    if($row['coupon_expire_date'] > $fecha_actual){
        $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT
                    t1.id_coupon,
                    t1.validity,
                    t1.coupon_expire_date,
                    
                    t2.id_coupon,
                    t2.p_id

                    FROM tbl_coupons t1
                    JOIN tbl_product t2
                    ON t1.id_coupon = t2.id_coupon
                    WHERE t1.validity='valid'
                    ");
        $statement->execute();
        $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        
        foreach($result as $col){
            $coupon_validity = $col['validity'];
            $p_id = $col['p_id'];
            $id_coupon = $col['id_coupon'];
        }
        
        if($coupon_validity == 'valid'){
        
            $statement = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE tbl_coupons SET validity=?");
            $statement->execute(array('expired'));
            //
                                       
            $statement = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE tbl_product SET id_coupon=? WHERE p_id=?");
            $statement->execute(array('0'));
        }else{
            echo "The Validity" . "<br>" . "of Coupon is: " . "<br>" . "<span style='font-weight:bold;' class='text-success'>" . $valid_coupon . "</span>";
        }                               
    }
?>
```

Comment: Traduce tu pregunta por favor. Me refiero a la pequeña sección que quedó escrita en inglés

Answer (score 0):

Casi nunca se requiere que la BD devuelva los ids de los registros actualizados, porque usualmente el desarrollador conoce los id de los registros que a actualizar, a menos que sea un update descontrolado. Entonces creo que la lógica del proyecto está un poco mal.

El primer SELECT trae un `t1.id_coupon`, así que con eso ya tienes el id del cupon y es la respuesta a tu pregunta.

El primer `UPDATE` [NO TIENE WHERE](https://www.google.com/search?q=update+without+where+meme&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X), lo cual dañará la tabla `tbl_coupons` puesto que le colocará *expired* a todos los registros.
Debería ser `... WHERE id_de_tbl_coupons=?` -> (`?` será `$id_coupon`).

Finalmente en el último UPDATE estás tratando de cambiar una columna `... SET id_coupon=? ...` que bien podría ser una llave foránea, así que por lógica relacional no puedes poner cualquier valor ahí. Si es posible y ese campo soporta valores NULL, tendrías que hacer `SET id_coupon=NULL` y si no permite nulos, entonces setearla al un registro default de `tbl_coupons` que signifique "sin cupon".